# Oracle Virtual Box current version no option for Win8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install the Win10 64Bit technical preview in VirtualBox VM, but I keep getting errors.  While digging into this I found online many suggestions to set the Windows version of the VM to "Windows 8.1 (64Bit)".  Problem is, I don't have that option, even though VirtualBox says I'm on the most recent version.

Where is this option and how can I correct?

Comment: Which version of VB are you using? Is you Windows 7 host 32 or 64 bit?  Does your CPU and motherboard support VT-x or AMD-V?  Do you have any other hypervisors installed on the host?

Comment: VirtualBox 4.2.12 (when I ask it to update it says current), Host is 64bit Win7, AMD processor, so I believe AMD-V supported.  Only other hypervisor is WIndows Virtual PC.

Comment: "so I believe AMD-V supported." you'll need to confirm that, and ensure it's enabled.

Comment: Yeah, AMD-V confirmed and enabled.  I'm running some win7 32 and 64bit VMs, so no issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of VirtualBox is old.  They are currently up to v4.3.20.

Instead of trusting a now out-of-date update checker, head directly to the VirutalBox site and download the latest version.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

[Direct link to current version (4.3.20) for Windows](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.20/VirtualBox-4.3.20-96997-Win.exe)

Comment: Damn, that update checker threw me off.  Downloading the new version clearly shows the 8.1 option.